# pandas get column values using UTC index

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas Dataframe with an index using UTC time and a column with data (in the example the column "value_1").

My question is: How could I create a new column in which each value is the value of the first column but 20 seconds later. Using the example below, I would get for the first value of this second column the value at the moment "2011-01-01 00:00:20".

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np

data_1 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods = 1000, freq ='S'))
data_1['value_1'] = 100 + np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(1000, 1))
data_1['value_2'] = ??¿¿
```

I don't know if it would be possible if I change the index to a different format.

I have seen that pandas have some useful functionalities to work with time series but I have not found the one in order to solve this problem yet.

Thank-you in advance.

Comment: Since your data is equally spaced by `20 sec`, you can do `data_1['value_2'] = data_1['value_1'].shift(-20)`.

Comment: Thank-you! It is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can either use `shift` with the value of seconds you want to use (here 20):

```
data_1['value_2'] = data_1['value_1'].shift(-20)
```

or can reindex with the index + 20s and get values with `to_numpy`:

```
data_1['value_2'] = data_1['value_1'].reindex(data_1['value_1'].index+pd.Timedelta(seconds=20)).to_numpy()
```

Comment: Thank-you for your answer.